# Command Not Found Error in Jenkins Builds

Tags: jenkins, testing, amazon-ec2, pytest, code-coverage

I am trying to create a jenkins pipeline which takes in some python dependencies which is mentioned in `requirements.txt` in my code package. The issue is those dependencies are getting installed as I can see them in console outputs for that stage in Jenkins UI. But when I am running a cmd for that , I am facind `command not found` error. I am new to Jenkins and would like someone expertise on this to unblock me on my project.
Exact Dependency errors:

- In my EC2's dockerised jenkins (related to python):

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/image-opti-flow@tmp/durable-a6131a8c/script.sh: 1: python3: not found
```

- In my mac with Jenkins server running (related to Coverage):

```
/Users/keshavsingh/.jenkins/workspace/Testing Pipeline@tmp/durable-ca4ba100/script.sh: line 1: coverage: command not found
```

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: <My Github Repo Url> ]]])
            }
        }

        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh "python3 -m venv venv"
                sh ". venv/bin/activate"
                sh "pip3 install -r requirements.txt"
            }
        }

        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                sh "coverage run -m pytest"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

requirements.txt

```
coverage==6.0.2
pytest==7.3.1
pytest-cov==3.0.0
```

It would be great if someone can unblock me on this and I am ready to more information regarding issue.

I am trying to run coverage cmd so to have tests with coverage too.

I was expecting Jenkins Job to succeed.

Comment: 1 - The issue on your Mac is separate from the issue in the EC2 instance. 2 - Have you tried entering the container that will run the job (by default probably the Jenkins container, but could be different by configuration) and tried running `python3` in that? 3 - What is the container that you are with? Is it `jenkins/jenkins:latest`?

Comment: Ok lets drop container case right now. In my mac I have installed jenkins directly with brew cmd So, question is specific to jenkins I guess. Because if i know what am I missing normally. I can then do that with changes in my other jenkins on docker in ec2? So, my query is more focused on jenkins side I guess

Comment: @KeshavSingh you should enter container and see if hte pyhton3 is there,I idoubt so.